# c++: implicit conversion order

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

I've a (member-)fuction overloaded like this:

```
bool foo(bool);
int foo(int);
float foo(float);
...
std::string foo( std::string const&);
```

for a couple of build-in-types but not for `const char*`. Calling `foo("beauty is only skin-deep");`, to my big suprise, called the bool-variant of the foo function. This leads to my questions:

**QUESTION:** Is there a well defined implicit conversion order for build-in-types

**NOT THE QUESTION:** How to avoid implicit conversion. How evil is implicit conversion. ...

**EDIT:** removed question about implicit converstion order for user-defined-questions

Comment: It should be 1 question at a time so can you pick just one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

all build-in conversions take place before user defined ones

pointer -> bool is a 'Boolean conversions' (needed for if(pointer) notation), last of 'numeric conversions'

'const char*' -> std::string is a 'user defined conversion' as from language point of view, std::string is a user defined type.

Unfortunately simplest solution is to write proper overload of fun(const char*), or to avoid fun(bool) vs fun(std::string) overloads